# Hyper-V CentOS 6.2 errors after LIC 3.3 installation

Tags: linux, centos, hyper-v

I have CentOS 6.2 with LIC 3.3 (Hyper-V), everything is working fine but I have some errors in my /var/log/messages

1. "eth0: Dropping NETIF_F_SG since no checksum feature."
2. "SRAT: Hotplug area too small" (only with more then 4Gb of RAM)

Are this issues critical? Can I somehow fix it?